# Class property looses scope AND can't be set after setTimeout

Tags: flash, actionscript, scope, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

Here's a very simplified version of my project.

I have a class file:

```
class MyClass{

public var myNumberStoredInClass:Number;

// constructor
function MyClass(myNumber:Number){
    this.myNumberStoredInClass = myNumber;
};

// some method
function DoStuffMethod(){
    trace(this.myNumberStoredInClass);
};

}; // end class
```

I have a normal .as file from which I can access this.myNumberStoredInClass with no problems with MyClass.myNumberStoredInClass until I call setTimeout for a method in the class:

```
function ASFileFunction(){

    trace(MyClass.myNumberStoredInClass); // works fine

    setTimeout(MyClass.DoStuffMethod, 7500);

};
```

When DoStuffMethod is triggered in the class file the trace of myNumberStoredInClass returns 'Undefined'. I've used the value in many other functions in the .as file just fine but after the setTimeout it's lost.

What's really odd is that I can change DoStuffMethod to the following and myNumberStoredInClass is still Undefined:

```
function DoStuffMethod(){

// I've tried watching this in debug mode and it just won't set, remains Undefined


myNumberStoredInClass = 10; 

    trace(myNumberStoredInClass); // returns Undefined
};
```

I've tried using this.myNumberStoredInClass in DoStuffMethod but the result is the same. I just can't set or retrieve the variable! If I do a trace immediately after the setTimeout the value is there, but once the setTimeout fires then the value can not be set.

I have to use AS2 for this.

Any ideas? Many thanks.

EDIT: Tried adding the object to the setTimeout call as per the documentation suggested by Sant gMirian but still the same result.

Comment: That's a setTimeout scope problem, look here, it's setInterval page, but setTimeout's scope works identically
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000600.html

Comment: Thanks. Tried adding the object to the arguments but still can't change the variable from Undefined. Would you mind posting an example with my code in case I've not got the syntax right?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no Flash CS6 to test a code, so can give just suggestion, try to make variable and function static, e.g. static public function DoStuffMethod() and static public var myNumberStoredInClass:Number;

Comment: Changing the variable to static worked, thanks a lot. I wonder why that is? Would you like to post as an answer so I can mark it solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A closure should work. Your code:

```
 setTimeout(MyClass.DoStuffMethod, 7500);
```

becomes:

```
 setTimeout(function () { MyClass.DoStuffMethod() }, 7500);
```

By the way, I assume that *MyClass* is an instance of your class, not your class definition.

This should also work:

```
function haveStuffDone () : void {
    MyClass.DoStuffMethod();
}
setTimeout (haveStuffDone, 7500);
```

where *haveStuffDone* is a function defined in the same context you call *setTimeout* from.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot that works well. After reading up on closures I don't understand how it works though, specifically: in my original code all of the class properties had lost scope after the setTimeout. Closures ensure that variables available to the 'outer' function are available to the 'inner' one... but what does that have to do with my class? Is it because the closure function retains the scope of the class members during the setTimeout call? Thanks again.

Comment: Closures "freeze" the scope available to them when they are declared. 

Have a look at this page: [as3-fundamentals/functions](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/functions.html), and do a search for **Function closures** — the section is to the bottom of the text. The text refers to a missing example, though :-(

Comment: Great link, thanks. For anyone else wondering about this I thought this line from that page sums it up nicely: "A function closure is an object that contains a snapshot of a function and its lexical environment. A function's lexical environment includes all the variables, properties, methods, and objects in the function's scope chain, along with their values."