# Maintain variables during setTimeout within same class

Tags: flash, actionscript, scope, settimeout, actionscript-2

How can I call setTimeout without class properties and other variables loosing scope and becoming undefined? The answer to [this question regarding variable scope with setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270228/class-property-looses-scope-and-cant-be-set-after-settimeout) was to use a function closure so a 'snapshot' of the in-scope variables was taken and maintained during the setTimeout. This does not seem to work within a class however. For example

```
class MyClass

public var MyVar:Number;

Function A_Closure(){
     FunctionC();
};

Function B(){
     MyVar = 10;
     setTimeout(A_Closure, 1000);
};

Function C(){
     trace("MyVar = " + MyVar); // returns Undefined
};

}; // End class
```

This returns Undefined for MyVar. If I move Function A_Closure to a non-class .as file everything works OK and MyVar = 10, but this seems like a very hacky approach. Is there a recognised way to use setTimeout within a class?

I'm restricted to AS2 for this project (Scaleform within CryEngine).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this the AS2-way the solution to call functions while keeping them 'linked' to instance variables would be to use a [Delegate](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00002285.html).

Your setTimeout line would be changed to look like this:

setTimeout(Delegate.create(this, FunctionC), 1000);

I've never used scaleform myself, but the [documentation](https://gameware.autodesk.com/scaleform/developer/doc/4.0/clik/) suggests Delegate is available in the library as `gfx.utils.Delegate`, this is different from the Adobe version but the call looks the same.

Delegates are no magic. By creating a function with parameters that creates another function that uses those parameters you are 'storing' those parameters when you call the first function. (The important part is that the function has to be *defined* inside the other function, not just *called*). This is probably what you were trying to do in your `A_Closure` function.

Psuedocode based on how it's done in javascript:

```
   function createClosure(obj) {
      return function () {
          // this if not a 'universal' solution like Delegate
          // because it calls this specific function
          obj.FunctionC();
      }
   };
```

Now you should update your setTimeout() function to something like this:

```
setTimeout(createClosure(this), 1000);
```

All code is from memory, I didn't test it so there might be errors.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion and apologies for the delay responding. The Delegate method works excellently to call the function and to preserve the variables but unfortunately the setTimeout seems to loose it's time parameter & executes immediately regardless of what value is provided. I've searched for some time for an example showing a Delegate with a setTimout but have come up empty handed. Do you have any examples?

Comment: Looks like you accidentally call the function instead of passing the reference to the function. Do you use 'FunctionC' in the creation of the delegate, and not accidentally 'FunctionC()'? The latter is an invocation of the function, where the former is just a reference to the function - the reference is the one you need.

Comment: Yes, I was calling rather than passing the reference. Problem solved, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing "this" in a closure in your calling function so it doesn't copy the myvar.

Example.

```
function a() {
    var scope:MyClass = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        scope.MyVar = 0;  // this should hit the actual value of the class
    }, 1000);
}
```